# Which test to use: 3x2 controlled with binary outcome

Tags: anova, binary-data

I am planning a study but I am not quite sure which test fits the most:
There is an experiment with two factors I do control. Factor A has 2 groups, factor B has 3 groups. My total sample is randomly distributed to these six treatment groups, every group has the same sample size.

E.g. my results could look like this:

__ B1_B2_B3__

A1 | 5 | 12 | 14

A1 | 6 | 9 | 8

So the numbers in the cells are amounts of outcome "1" in the corresponding group.

I want to test between subjects if treatment with these factors have an effect on the binary outcome. Is it legit to test that with an ANOVA or do I overlook something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using logistic regression, which is a statistical model usually taken to apply to binary outcome data.

In R this could be run using:

```
model1 <- glm(Outcome ~ A*B, data=dat, family="binomial")
anova(model1, test="Chisq") # sequential significance tests of factors
```

Comment: ok with this approach I create a model from the data (with the glm() function) and after that I test the model fit with a chi-square test, am I right?

Comment: That is correct.  The Chisq test will sequentially test additional variables in the model for significance (starting with the null model and ending with the full model).